# How to search for words from the extracted tabular data of pdf in Python

Tags: python, tabula

I am able to successfully extract the tabular data from the pdf.

But, I would like to search keywords ex: 8.0 from the extracted data, If it finds then It considers as Test passed.

```
for file in glob.glob(dir + "batch*.pdf"):
    # print(file)
    if file.endswith('.pdf'):
        f=(open(file, "rb"))
        pdf = PyPDF4.PdfFileReader(f)
        count = 0
        count = pdf.numPages
        print("No.Of Pages:", count)
        while count >= 0:
            df = tabula.read_pdf(
                file, 
                stream=True,
                guess=False, 
                pages="all", 
                multiple_tables=True
            )
            # df.head(11)
            print(df)
            break
            search_keywords=[ ‘Year','8.0']
            for sentence in df:
               lst = []
               for word in search_keywords:    
                      if word in sentence:
                            lst.append(word)
               print('{0} key word(s) in sentence: {1}'.format(len(lst), ', '.join(lst)))

        f.close()
    else:
        print("not in format")
```

How can I achive the above

Comment: did you try to add if "what you search" in content:  ?

Comment: Tried this,but no luck                             search_keywords=[ ‘Year','8.0']

for sentence in df:
    lst = []
    for word in search_keywords:
        if word in sentence:
            lst.append(word)
    print('{0} key word(s) in sentence: {1}'.format(len(lst), ', '.join(lst)))